# OCUnit tests alway pass if they contain a method named 'name'

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocunit

Esteemed OCUnit testers,

OCUnit tests always pass if they contain a method named 'name', e.g:

```
#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>

@interface Tests : SenTestCase

@end

@implementation Tests

- (NSString *)name
{
    return @"Howard";
}

- (void)testSomeTest
{
    STFail(@"Unit tests are not implemented yet in Tests");
}

@end
```

Passes! I am running under XCode 4.

If I change 'name' to some other name then it is fine, i.e. it fails. Any idea why 'name' is a reserved name in OCUnit? Anyway to get round this? It is part of a protocol I am trying to test.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, -- Howard.

Answer (score 1):

SenTestCase.m already has an internal method called `-name`:

https://github.com/jy/SenTestingKit/blob/master/SenTestCase.m

I presume you're trying to test the results of a delegate protocol. Try pulling the delegate-providing test code into a separate object, outside of the test fixture.